# connecting to a computer in LAN and send cmd commands

Tags: vb6, remote-access, remote-server

I need to connect to a computer in LAN
and to open CMD in the remote computer
and send a command (for example ping www.google.com - but other commands..)

I thought to open a server on the remote computer and a client in my computer and every time to send a command as a string to the server side, and to send that command to the cmd (i know it's easy with c++)

is there another way to do this?
is there a way in vb6 to open cmd in a remote computer and to send a command?

the reason i write this here is because the client side will be written in vb6
the client is not written, but i will put it in a program written in vb6

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use WMI. You could copy over a batch file, script or an executable and then use WMI to execute it remotely.

You can use [Win32_Process.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as described here: [Creating Processes Remotely](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: but to start the batch file i'll need to connect to the remote computer right?
so a server should run on that pc

Comment: @ro-E Yes, but that "server" is built in. You write code to connect to WMI on the remote computer and the tells it to execute the code. That way you don't have to write your own custom server software. The only thing is that you'll need to have the correct permissions, which I think are the same ones as described in the question Alex links to (I think Psexec might be using WMI internally).

Answer (score 1):

You could use Psexec from SysInternals and avoid writing anything for the server side.
You could also use telnet/ssh.

Comment: thank you!
the problem is to build a server, is there a way in vb to send commands to a remote computer w/o building a server and running it forever.
because to build a server is not a problem, but i dont know if it's the best solution - the computers are connected to the same network (there is a wire from one to the other..)

Comment: You can use the existing windows telnet server, you don't have to build one. And if you use PsExec you also don't need to create a server as it will use existing services. You just need to make sure you have the necessary permissions. See http://serverfault.com/questions/280482/how-to-use-psexec-without-admin-privileges-on-target-machine